# Build a dynamic APEX instruction from arguments received in String

Tags: apex

I am building a helper function to retrieve the picklist values of different fields and objects and passing them to my LWC. I was wondering if there's a way to "build" the String of the sentence in order to create a dynamic instruction.

I tried building the String and then passing it, but of course, it resulted in a type error.

The question is: How can I build this dynamic instruction in which I pass an Object name and a field name? (see an example for a better understanding of what I am trying to achieve, please).

This is what tried so far:

```
  @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
  public static List<String> getCallPicklistValues(
    String objectName,
    String fieldName
  ) {
    List<String> callOptions = new List<String>();
    String buildInstruction =
      objectName +
      '.' +
      fieldName +
      '.' +
      'getDescribe()';

    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = buildInstruction;
    //Complete instruction is:
    //Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Task.call_result__c.getDescribe();
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> fieldOptions = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();

    for (Schema.PicklistEntry ple : fieldOptions) {
      callOptions.add(String.ValueOf(ple.getValue()));
    }

    return callOptions;
  }
}
```

Comment: it's done via Global Schema, I'll write a full answer in few minutes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this what you're looking for.
Key parts `Schema.getGlobalDescribe();` and `describeSObjectResult.fields.getMap().get(fieldName).getDescribe()`

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<String> getCallPicklistValues(
        String objectName,
        String fieldName
) {
    // method for accessing all available SObjectTypes
    Map<String, SObjectType> globalDescribe = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
    if (!globalDescribe.containsKey(objectName)) {
        // handle error
    }
    DescribeSObjectResult describeSObjectResult = globalDescribe.get(objectName).getDescribe();

    if (!describeSObjectResult.fields.getMap().containsKey(fieldName)) {
        // handle error
    }

    // getting field describe dynamically
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = describeSObjectResult.fields.getMap().get(fieldName).getDescribe();
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> fieldOptions = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
    List<String> callOptions = new List<String>();
    
    for (Schema.PicklistEntry ple : fieldOptions) {
        callOptions.add(String.ValueOf(ple.getValue()));
    }

    return callOptions;
}
```

Feel free to comment if you need any additional assistance

Comment: Yes, works perfectly. It's exactly what I needed. Thank you.